# Error on rendering linestring

Tags: python, tiles, spatialite, mapnik, geodjango

I am using Mapnik 2.0.1rc0 on a Windows 7 with python 2.7 32bits inside a GeoDjango App using xml. The datasource come from spatialite 4.0. My tiling script can render polygon and point features correctly but linestring are just not displayed. The tiles are empty, without error. I can see the background of the tiles, but no trace of any lines when zooming in and out.

Does anybody have an idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Burton,

Never seen anything like that. Can you post a link to a sample of your data so I can try to replicate?

Comment: Thank you, if you can test the data (simple lines drawn in QGIS) I will know if the problem is in the code or the data. https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9lmo_x3K3OkcHE0RHVCSy1qRFU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have tested the same data and code with PosGis 2.0 instead and it works normally. I think there is something wrong in the way mapnik makes its queries in spatialite.

Comment: I have noticed that Mapnik creates a file such sql3.db.index in the folder of the spatialite db. When this file is deleted the features are well rendered in the tiles. Please see [this post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58349/mapnik-weird-tiles-rendering-when-used-with-spatialite) for more details on this issue: