# Mapnik - Weird tiles rendering when used with spatialite

Tags: openlayers-2, tiles, spatialite, mapnik, geodjango

I use Mapnik in an GeoDjango App with Spatialite 4.0 as backend. There is something weird with the tiles that I suspect might be related with a bad handling of mbr with spatialite.

If you look at those two images, the first is the tiles rendered in OpenLayers with a map.zoomToExtent on the features. If you look at the triangle in atlantic ocean you will see that the feature is not rendered entirely by Mapnik. The second image show the entire feature not tiled.

[image][image]

If I zoom in, the triangle continue to not be tiled correctly. If I zoom out a lot it finally appears.

I use this query in Mapnik:

```
query = '(select ' + geometryField + ', "id" from "shapefile_feature" where' + ' shapefile_id=' + str(shapefile.id) + ') as geom'
datasource = mapnik.SQLite(file='C:\mygeosite\sqlite3\sql3.db',
                                table=query,
                                srid=4326,
                                geometry_field=geometryField)

featureLayer = mapnik.Layer("featureLayer")
featureLayer.datasource = datasource
```

Comment: Where did the data come from? That is, what is the shapefile?

Comment: Its a Multipolygon shapefile converted by FME from MapInfo format. I did the triangle inside the geodjango app with the geodjango.admin tool. I have verify the geometry of the triangle in spatialite, and it is conform with the other features geometry.

Comment: I have seen the same problem with point shapefile created with QGIS. If a point is drawn far from other points, it doesnt appear in the tiles at certain zoom level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have a part of the answer. I use only one table to store every features of every shapefiles uploaded in the geodjango app. **Mapnik creates a spatial index on this table inside a distinct file named *sql3.db.index*.** I think the problem is related to that spatial index, because when it is recreated after deletion, the features are displayed correctly. It seems this index is not updated when a feature geometry is modified.

Does anybody have more info about that? Which of Spatialite, GeoDjango or Mapnik is creating the sql3.db.index file. How I could manage to make it updated when a feature is modified?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Perhaps try on mapnik web site?

Comment: This [paper describes a SpatiaLite scenario whereby the spatial index can become corrupted](http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-3.0.0-BETA/SpatialIndex-Update.pdf) if the table doesn't have a primary key specified. ..it seems odd to me that Mapnik would be to blame for the spatial index getting goofed---unless Mapnik is manipulating the db (I thought it was just a rendering engine?) I would expect maintaining the indices between Insert/Update calls to be the responsibility of the database. Am I wrong?

Comment: I dont know if Mapnik is to blame, but I have notice that when tiles are rendered, the sql3.db.index is created if it was not already. This file is not generated by other process. And for Spatialite, the R-Tree Index is suppose to be stored in a virtual table inside the db not in a separate file.

Comment: I see you asked your [question](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mapnik/IBBajSvG66Q) over in the Mapnik group. :)